# State is not showing up in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to Redux, bare with me.

I'm working on a basic news app with TypeScript and React on the frontend, and Node.js and Express on the backend. I recently started integrating Redux into my app.

When a user logs in to my app, I'm currently redirecting them to their profile page (component). The profile component has a useEffect that will then call my backend API (with Thunk) to get the user and put it in the Redux store if it can't already find it there. The API returns the user object (I can verify in my terminal that the API is returning a user object), but the user never ends up in the store, and therefore I can't render any of their information. I'll attach all the relevant code in hopes that maybe someone can spot the problem.

authReucer.ts:

```
import { User } from "../../../../shared/User";
import {
  AuthDispatchTypes,
  USER_SUCCESS,
  USER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADING,
} from "../actions/authActionsTypes";

interface UserRes {
  user: User;
  status: number;
  authenticated: boolean;
}

export interface AuthState {
  loading: boolean;
  user?: UserRes;
  authenticated: boolean;
}

const defaultState: AuthState = {
  loading: false,
  authenticated: false,
};

const authReducer = (
  state: AuthState = defaultState,
  action: AuthDispatchTypes
): AuthState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        authenticated: false,
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        loading: true,
        authenticated: false,
      };
    case USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        authenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

authActionTypes.ts:

```
import { User } from "../../../../shared/User";

export const USER_LOADING = "USER_LOADING";
export const USER_FAIL = "USER_FAIL";
export const USER_SUCCESS = "USER_SUCCESS";

interface UserLoading {
  type: typeof USER_LOADING;
}

interface UserFail {
  type: typeof USER_FAIL;
}

interface UserSuccess {
  type: typeof USER_SUCCESS;
  payload: {
    user: User;
    status: number;
    authenticated: boolean;
  };
}

export type AuthDispatchTypes = UserLoading | UserFail | UserSuccess;
```

authActions.ts:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import {
  AuthDispatchTypes,
  USER_LOADING,
  USER_FAIL,
  USER_SUCCESS,
} from "./authActionsTypes";

export const setUser = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthDispatchTypes>) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADING,
    });

    const res = await axios.get("auth/login/success");

    dispatch({
      type: USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_FAIL,
    });
  }
};
```

Profile.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";
import { setUser } from "../store/actions/authActions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { AuthState } from "../store/reducers/authReducer";

export const Profile = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userState = useSelector<AuthState, AuthState["user"]>(
    (state) => state.user
  );
const authenticated = useSelector<AuthState, AuthState["authenticated"]>(
    (state) => state.authenticated
  );

useEffect(() => {
    // Check if there's a user authenticated but we dont yet have it
    if (userState === undefined && authenticated) {
      dispatch(setUser);
    }
  });

return (
    <div>
      <Navbar
      //authenticated={authenticated}
      //handleNotAuthenticated={handleNotAuthenticated}
      />
      <h1>Profile</h1>
      <h2>{userState && userState.user.username}</h2>
      <h2>{userState && userState.user.email}</h2>
      <img src={userState && userState.user.photo} alt={"profile"} />
      <h2>Your News Sources</h2>
      { <ul>
        {user &&
          user.sources.map((source: any) => {
            return <li key={source.url}>{source.name}</li>;
          })}
      </ul> }
    </div>
  );
};
```

index.ts:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { createStore, Store, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

const store: Store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: I think you use combineReducers, have a close look at the redux devtools and see what actions are dispatched and how they change the state.

Comment: What is `user && user.sources` in Profile.tsx? There also appears to be some not-quite-correct JSX around rendering this data.

Comment: I do combine the reducers, I forgot to share that code: ` import authReducer from "./authReducer";

import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;`

Comment: user is the user object inside of the userState. In authActions its 'res.data' and then placed into the 'user' property.

Comment: In the Redux Dev Tools there aren't any actions showing up, I don't think any of them are firing off. I'm just not sure why.

Comment: Where is `user` defined though? From what I can see it isn't declared anywhere. Are you saying it should really be `userState`?

Comment: I have a user interface that I'm importing from "...../shared/user": `export interface User {
  _id: any;
  provider: string;
  googleId: string;
  username: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  photo: string;
  sources: Array;
}
`

Comment: The user property inside of the userState is of type 'User'.

Comment: I discovered part of the problem (actually most of the problem): I wasn't invoking the setUser function inside of dispatch. Forgot to add '()'. Now I can see the state in the RDT, there's an auth object, and inside there's 3 properties: authenticated, loading and user (which is the user object, of the User interface). Now I have to find out why none of the properties are rendering from state into the JSX.

Comment: Ok, so I'll guess that `user` variable I've been asking about down in your render return is supposed to really be `userState.user` since you haven't confirmed anything. Cool, so it sounds like you got your redux state updating. Have you tried a `conslole.log(userState);`, `debugger` or set a breakpoint on the line after selecting that state? If so, what values do you see when the component rerenders?

Comment: When I console.log the userState, it comes out undefined, even though I can see it in the Redux devtools (see screenshot): EDIT - Cant add screenshot in comment, but the userState IS showing up in RDT.

Comment: This is what the state looks like: auth: {loading: false, authenticated: true, user: user}. The user property is an object with three properties: user: {success: true, message: some-message, user: user}. That last user property is what holds the ACTUAL user data, such as name, email, id...

Comment: I found the issue, I'll try and explain it as best as I can. I wasn't properly accessing my state - I was getting state from my rootReducer, but my state retrieval code was suited to getting state from the authReducer. Basically, I needed to go one level deeper to the rootReducer to get the expected state.